# Adding a String Array inside an Object

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to add a string array inside my object.

Here is the code for my object:

```
    public Question(int id, String question, String[] answers) {
    this.id = id;
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
}
```

Here is where I'm having trouble

```
        questionList.add(
            new Question(
                    1,
                    "This is a question?",

    ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `String[]` literal syntax, like

```
new String[] { "a", "b", "c" }
```

**or** you could rewrite the constructor to take a *varargs* parameter. Like,

```
public Question(int id, String question, String... answers) {
    this.id = id;
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
}
```

And then you can pass a `String[]` literal ***or*** use comma separated answers (or a `String[]` literal) to instantiate it.

```
new Question(
    1,
    "This is a question?",
    "This is an answer.", "This is another answer."
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to send in answers as the third param. Also, it's not stated where your define questionList.

To create your 'answers' parameter, one way would be.

```
String[] answers = new String[]{"Answer 1", "Answer 2"};
```

You can also convert a list to an array.

```
String[] answers = Arrays.asList("Answer 1", "Answer 2").toArray(new String[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

A string array literal can be written as:

```
new String[] {"Hellow world", "Bo mundo", "Hola Mundo" }
```

In declarations you can avoid the 'new String[]' stuff, because java infer the type, but this is not the case. So, if you want to create a new question:

```
Question question = new Question(1, "2 + 2 = ?", new String[] {"1", "2", "42"});
```

Anyway, another functionality you could use to reduce such a verbosity is to use '...'. For example, if you write the following instead

```
public Question(int id, String question, String... answers) {
    this.id = id;
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
}
```

answers will still be an array of Strings, but you can call Question's constructors as a variable arguments function:

```
Question question = new Question(1, "2 + 2 = ?", "1", "2", "42"});
```

Where all the parameter after question are part of the answers array.